# php image upload with class.upload

Tags: php, image, upload

I am using [boostrap file upload](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) with [class.upload](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) from verot. All my code works fine, however I want to add the additional functionality of having a checkbox to determine how the script crops the images.

```
$handle->image_ratio_crop = true; // basically zooms in on the middle (default)
$handle->image_ratio_fill = true; // preserves ratio and adds white bars where needed
```

If the user checks image_ratio_fill next to the image then I want this to be used instead of the default in the script. Currently I have 4 image uploads available on the page. The following script iterates through each file and adds performs the necessary cropping .etc.

PHP:

```
function upImageSpec($table, $m_x, $m_y, $t_x, $t_y)
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $img_db_name = str_replace('s', '', $table); // this will replace the s with nothing so that it is user_image_1, project_image_1 for the db insertion
    // unchanging variables
    $ext = 'jpg';
    $upload_path = FRONTEND_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH . slash_item($table) . slash_item($id); // will not work with /images/
    // end unchanging variables
    $files = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['userfile'] as $k => $l) {
        foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
            if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
                $files[$i] = array();
            $files[$i][$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        // foreach variables
        $main_name = 'm_' . $id;
        $thumb_name = 't_' . $id;
        $count = $counter++;
        // end foreach variables
        $handle = new upload($file);
        if ($handle->uploaded) {
            // save uploaded image $m_x, $m_y
            $mi = sprintf("%s_%d", $main_name, $count);
            $full_src = REL_FRONTEND_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH . slash_item($table) . slash_item($id) . $mi . '.' . $ext;
            $handle->file_new_name_body = $mi;
            $handle->image_convert = $ext;
            $handle->allowed = array(
                'image/*'
            );
            $handle->file_max_size = MAX_IMAGE_FILE_SIZE;
            $handle->jpeg_quality = 95;
            $handle->image_resize = true;
            //$handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
            $handle->image_ratio_fill = true;
            $handle->image_x = $m_x;
            $handle->image_y = $m_y;
            $handle->file_overwrite = true;
            $handle->auto_create_dir = true;
            $handle->process($upload_path);
            if ($handle->processed) {
                Nemesis::update($table, "last_modified = NOW(), last_modified_by = '{$_SESSION[user_id]}', {$img_db_name}_image_{$count} = '{$full_src}'", "id = '{$id}'");
            } else {
                $msg = new Messages();
                $msg->add('e', $handle->error);
            }
            // thumbnail part, same as above, just w/ diff dimensions
        }
        unset($handle);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <?php if ($totalRows_projects > 0) { ?>
    <?php $msg = new Messages(); echo $msg->display(); ?>
    <h2>Project Images<?php if (!empty($row_projects['project_name'])) { echo ': ' . $row_projects['project_name']; }?></h2>
    <form action="framework/helpers/image_handler.php?type=upload&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <?php $counter = 1; while ($row = $resultImages->fetch_assoc()) { $count = $counter++; ?>
       <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
          <input type="hidden">
          <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 104px; height: 76px;"><span id="img<?php echo $count; ?>"><img src="<?php getThumb($row_projects["project_image_$count"]); ?>"></span></div>
          <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="width: 104px; height: 76px; line-height: 50px; "></div>
          <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="file<?php echo $count; ?>" class="search" multiple></span>
          <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
          <?php if (is_file(ROOT . $row_projects["project_image_$count"])) { ?><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.get('framework/helpers/image_remove.php',{ cmd: 'deleteImage', image: '<?php echo $row_projects["project_image_$count"]; ?>' } ,function(data){ $('#img<?php echo $count; ?>').html(data); });" class="fileupload-controls btn btn-danger" title="Deletion is permanent!">Remove Existing</a><?php } ?>
          <select name="cropfactor" class="select-ms">
             <option value="1">Ratio Crop</option>
             <option value="2">Ratio Fill</option>
          </select>
       </div>
       <?php } ?>
       <br><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Add Project Image" class="btn btn-success"><a id="back" href="projects.php" class="btn btn-space" title="No changes will be made">Skip to Projects</a><?php if (!empty($row_projects['youtube_link'])) { ?><a id="yt_image" href="framework/helpers/image_handler.php?type=youtube&id=<?php echo $id; ?>&link=<?php echo $row_projects['youtube_link']; ?>" class="btn btn-space" title="Add Youtube still as a main image">Get YouTube Thumb</a><?php } ?>
       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $MAX_IMAGE_FILE_SIZE ?>">
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

On post the upper code submits and is processed through the function above via image_handler.php

Code snippet:

```
case 'upload':
    if (checkIDExists()) {
        upImageSpec('projects', 458, 332, 104, 76);
        redirect('', true);
    } else {
        $msg = new Messages();
        $msg->add('e', QUERY_ID_ERROR);
        redirect('', true);
    }
    break;
```

How would one user the `cropfactor` field so that if changed to ratio fill the default (ratio crop) is switched off, and the `image_ratio_fill` is used. Assuming that other images on the page might want to be kept at the default. I have tried a simple if else statement which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

CropFactor in the form field should be

```
<select name="cropfactor[]" class="select-ms">
..
</select>
```

and in your function:

```
//after $id = $_GET['id']; add following
$cropfactor = $_POST['cropfactor'];
```

and for each of your files go through each value of $cropfactor

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // ... all other codes

    if ($handle->uploaded) {
        //...everything else        

        if($cropfactor[$counter] == 1) {
           $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
        } else {
           $handle->image_ratio_fill = true;
        }

    }    
}
```

Hope it helps.

note: code not tested.

Comment: yes, correct. But $counter should start from 0 not 1 in your case. Or just $cropfactor[$count-1]

Comment: im sorry, not understanding, why should it start from 0 and not 1?. furthermore, i added that i am processing the function through an intermediary php file as seen above. will the $_POST carry over to the function. for example if i have: this form which submits to a image handler that houses the function call (but not the function logic itself which is in another php file included by the framework)

Comment: It should start from 0 because in html form you'll put - <select name="cropfactor[]"> which will give you array of values starting from 0. Yes all POST and GET variables will be accessible in your function. Try to implement my suggestions and if it doesn't help, I will help you to rewrite your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have already most of the code in place. First thing is changing the `Select` name such that it can be associated with the given image (one `Select` per image and one name per `Select`). You can easily do that by relying on the same methodology you are using, that is:

```
<select name="cropfactor<?php echo $count; ?>" class="select-ms">
    <option value="1">Ratio Crop</option>
    <option value="2">Ratio Fill</option>
</select>
```

The selected value will be submitted with the `Form`, and then retrieved via `$_POST[$cropName]`, where `$cropName` is the name of the given `Select`.

Your PHP code would become then:

```
$cropName = "cropfactor" . $count;
$handle->image_ratio_crop = ($_POST[$cropName] == "1");
$handle->image_ratio_fill = ($_POST[$cropName] == "2");
```